# Issue creating a calculator

Tags: java, calculator

I'm a beginner at java and I've been trying to make a calculator using Swing. So far everything is good, but I'm having trouble with how the number pad will work. I want the calculator's output to be a float value, but I want it to be so that if you click "1", the output will display "1", not "1.00".  How could I go about this?

Also, I cannot think of a way to append a number to another number. For example, if I input 1 then input 2, the output would be 1.02, not 12. How do I get the program to make the output be a whole number when possible?

Comment: Can you post your code snippet?

Comment: Weak title. Rewrite to summarize your specific technical issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question: You first want to check that there are no digits after the decimal point when just displaying 1 instead of 1.00. To do so you can check that this actually is the case with this if statement:

```
if(number % 1.0f == 0)
```

next, you want to convert this number into a string that just displays the number without the decimal points, to do so you can cast number to an int and then convert it into a string with:

```
String.valueOf((int) number)
```

For the second question: To append a new digit to the number I would suggest generating a string with the number the user enters using StringBuilder. In practice it would look something like:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// when user presses "2" button for example:
sb.append("2");
```

In the end you want to convert this generated String into a float in order to perform calculations on it, which you can do with:

```
float value = Float.valueOf(sb.toString());
```